# How do I link each image in my CSS slideshow to a different page on my site?

Tags: css, hyperlink, slideshow

I built a pure css slideshow and it works as far as rotating the images.  But I also want the images to be clickable links that take you to the relevant pages of the website and that's where I'm having trouble.

The images do appear as links, but they all point to the url for the 4th slide, and I can't figure out what I need to change to get the links to rotate in unison with their corresponding images.

**UPDATE:** When I changed the z-index as suggested by user45250's answer, it made all the images point to the link for the first slide instead of the last. But I need each image to point to a *different* page.

**UPDATE 2:** I was pretty sure that the z-index was related to the problem somehow, and I am now able to get the links to rotate.  I set the z-index to 4 for each image for the point at which its opacity was set to 1 instead of 0 (see updated code below) **BUT** the links *still* won't synchronize with the images.  Now when the slideshow loads, the links cycle quickly through all four while the first image is still up, and then stop at the fourth link until the slideshow restarts.  What else can I change to get this to work??

Here's my html:

```
<div id="show">
   <a href="newproduct.html" class="img1 slide"><div>
    <img class="slideimg" src="images/new.png" alt="New Product"></div>
   </a>
   <a href="joinlist.html" class="img2 slide"><div>
    <img class="slideimg" src="images/mailinglist.png" alt="Join Our Mailing List!"></div>
   </a>
   <a href="firesale.html" class="img3 slide"><div>
     <img class="slideimg" src="images/firesale.png" alt="Shop the Fire Sale"></div>
   </a>
   <a href="giftcards.html" class="img4 slide"><div>
     <img class="slideimg" src="images/giftcards.png" alt="Buy Gift Cards"></div>
   </a>
</div>
```

**UPDATED** CSS:

```
/* slideshow frame */


    #show {
      display:block;
        margin:0px;
        position: relative;
        padding:0px;
        border: 3px solid #000000;
        z-index:1;
    }

    #show .slide {
        position: absolute;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-align: center;
    }

.img1 {
animation: img1 40s infinite;
-o-animation: img1 40s infinite;
-moz-animation: img1 40s infinite;
-webkit-animation: img1 40s infinite;
}

.img2 {
animation:img2 40s infinite;
o animation: img2 40s infinite;
moz animation: img2 40s infinite;
-webkit-animation: img2 40s infinite;
}

.img3 {
animation:img3 40s infinite;
o animation: img3 40s infinite;
moz animation: img3 40s infinite;
-webkit-animation: img3 40s infinite;
}

.img4 {
animation:img4 40s infinite;
o animation: img4 40s infinite;
moz animation: img4 40s infinite;
-webkit-animation: img4 40s infinite;
}

/* keyframing */

@-webkit-keyframes img1 {
0% {opacity: 0;}
25% {opacity: 1;
z-index:4;}
50% {opacity: 0;}
75% {opacity: 0;}
100% {opacity: 0;}
}

@keyframes img1 {
0% {opacity: 0;}
25% {opacity: 1;
z-index:4;}
50% {opacity: 0;}
75% {opacity: 0;}
100% {opacity: 0;}
}

@-moz-keyframes img1 {
0% {opacity: 0;}
25% {opacity: 1;
z-index:4;}
50% {opacity: 0;}
75% {opacity: 0;}
100% {opacity: 0;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes img2 {
0% {opacity: 0;}
25% {opacity: 0;}
50% {opacity: 1;
z-index:4;}
75% {opacity: 0;}
100% {opacity: 0;}
}

@keyframes img2 {
0% {opacity: 0;}
25% {opacity: 0;}
50% {opacity: 1;
z-index:4;}
75% {opacity: 0;}
100% {opacity: 0;}
}

@-moz-keyframes img2 {
0% {opacity: 0;}
25% {opacity: 0;}
50% {opacity: 1;
z-index:4;}
75% {opacity: 0;}
100% {opacity: 0;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes img3 {
0% {opacity: 0;}
25% {opacity: 0;}
50% {opacity: 0;}
75% {opacity: 1;
z-index:4;}
100% {opacity: 0;}
}

@keyframes img3 {
0% {opacity: 0;}
25% {opacity: 0;}
50% {opacity: 0;}
75% {opacity: 1;
z-index:4;}
100% {opacity: 0;}
}

@-moz-keyframes img3 {
0% {opacity: 0;}
25% {opacity: 0;}
50% {opacity: 0;}
75% {opacity: 1;
z-index:4;}
100% {opacity: 0;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes img4 {
0% {opacity: 0;}
25% {opacity: 0;}
50% {opacity: 0;}
75% {opacity: 0;}
100% {opacity: 1;
z-index:4;}
}

@keyframes img4 {
0% {opacity: 0;}
25% {opacity: 0;}
50% {opacity: 0;}
75% {opacity: 0;}
100% {opacity: 1;
z-index:4;}
}

@-moz-keyframes img4 {
0% {opacity: 0;}
25% {opacity: 0;}
50% {opacity: 0;}
75% {opacity: 0;}
100% {opacity: 1;
z-index:4;}
}
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't test your code, but can you try to add z-index to set ordering for each img:

```
.img1 {
z-index:4;
}

.img2 {
z-index:3;
}

.img3 {
z-index:2;
}


.img4 {
z-index:1;
}
```

That gives the highest number to `img1` then to `img2` through `img4.`

Comment: Do you have any more ideas based on my updates?  You're right that the z-index was the key...but I still can't figure out the timing!